# Why isn't dependent type inffered by the compiler?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shapeless, dependent-type, type-level-computation

I'm learning shapeless and faced some misunderstading about dependent types. Here is the example:

```
object App {
  trait Converter[A]{
    type Output
    def convert(a: A): Output
  }

  implicit def toStringConverter[A]: Converter[A] = new Converter[A] {
    override type Output = String
    override def convert(a: A): String = s"Converted value = ${a.toString}"
  }

  def getConvertedValue[A](a: A)(implicit converter: Converter[A]) = converter.convert(a)


  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val someValue: String = getConvertedValue(new Object) //compiler error, type mismatch
    val someValue2 = getConvertedValue(new Object)        //fine
    println(someValue2) //prints the expected value
  }
}
```

I don't understand compile error in the first case. Compiler correctly finds the implicit value of `implicit def toStringConverter[A]` which has `override type Output = String`. So it has all the information to infer return type `String`.

Why does not it compile? Is there a way to make it infer the return type as `String` without parameterizing the output type?

Comment: This sounds like one of those Scala isn't Haskell moments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by specifying more precise return type for `toStringConverter`:

```
implicit def toStringConverter[A]: Converter[A] { type Output = String } = new Converter[A] { ... }
```

Or by not specifying it at all so the above type gets inferred, but that's not recommended for implicits.

> Compiler correctly finds the implicit value of implicit def toStringConverter[A] which has override type Output = String. So it has all the information to infer return type String.

It cannot depend on the *implementation* of `toStringConverter[A]`, only on its type.

Comment: You will typically find the "Aux pattern" used in situations like this. It's just a type alias for Alexey's type. 

`object Converter {
    type Aux[A, O] = Converter[A] { type Output = O }
  }
`

And then change signature to `implicit def toStringConverter[A]: Converter.Aux[A, String]`